# I am getting unexpected output

Tags: c, recursion

I assumed the output to be '0' for the following code but, I am getting the output as '3'.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int num_digit(int n);

int num_digit(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + num_digit(n/10);
}

int main() {
    int k  = num_digit(123);
    printf("%d\n",k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain why you expect output to be 0. Maybe start by telling us what `foo` is supposed to do.

Comment: The correct output for this program is 3. Why do you expect it to be different?

Comment: the function should return 0. Hence the code should print 0. Right?

Comment: Why? What does the function do? How about renaming it something other than `foo`. Something more descriptive.

Comment: Grab a debugger and run through the code line by line. That will show you what is happening and why the result is what it is

Comment: @P.W can you explain why the correct out put is 3.

Comment: @AnoCorff: Familiarize yourself with recursion. Base case and non-base case aspects of it.

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Thank you @Andreas i understand your concern. I will definitely keep it mind the next time i post something

Answer (score 2):

The following link provides an excellent source for learning C Recursion and as @MFisherKDX pointed out help solve my confusion.

> https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-recursion

After each time the recursion happens it returns a value.
adding up all the values :

```
0+1 = 1
1+1 = 2
2+1 = 3
```

gives the answer as 3.

Answer (score 2):

This is basic recursion. Just try to create a recursion tree for the program that you have written and you should be able to figure out why is the output that you see coming as 3.

You are expecting 0 as answer, only based on the last recursive call (terminating condition), but when a recursive call happens, there is a concept of activation records which are maintained in the form of Stack data structure.

The recursion tree will look something like what is shown in [Recursion Tree for shared code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtwAg.png)

```
num_digits(123) = 1 + num_digits(12)
num_digits(12)  = 1 + num_digits(1)
num_digits(1)   = 1 + num_digits(0)
num_digits(0)   = 0
```

Using substitution:

```
num_digits(123) = 1 + (1 + (1 + (0)))
```

Please follow the parenthesis above clearly and you should be able to absolutely understand the output that you were getting out of the code that you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion stack for your code is like below

```
1 + num_digit(123/10);
1 + num_digit(12/10);
1 + num_digit(1/10); //at this point your code will return 0 for num_digit(1/10)
```

and backtracking is like below

```
1+0=1
1+1=2
1+2=3
```

Hence the final answer is `3`